# How Can I Display Success message On Divi Contact Form Module

Tags: javascript, php, forms, contacts, divi

Hello I have a divi contact form module. website is not wordpress. I want to display a success message after user submits form. How can I go about it. Tried many ways.
The form appears below.

```
<div class="et_pb_module et_pb_contact_form_0 dct-contact-forn et_pb_contact_form_container clearfix"
                                             data-form_unique_num="0"
                                             id="et_pb_contact_form_0">


                                            <div class="et-pb-contact-message"><p>Thanks</p></div>
                                            
                                            <div class="et_pb_contact">
                                                <form action="contact.php" class="et_pb_contact_form clearfix"
                                                      method="post">
                                                    <p class="et_pb_contact_field et_pb_contact_field_0 et_pb_contact_field_last"
                                                       data-id="name_2" data-type="input">


                                                        <label class="et_pb_contact_form_label"
                                                               for="name">Name</label>
                                                        <input class="input" data-field_type="input" data-required_mark="required" id="name"
                                                               name="name" placeholder="Name"
                                                               type="text" value="">
                                                    </p>
                                                    <p class="et_pb_contact_field et_pb_contact_field_1 et_pb_contact_field_half"
                                                       data-id="email" data-type="email">


                                                        <label class="et_pb_contact_form_label" for="email">Email
                                                            Address</label>
                                                        <input class="input" data-field_type="email" data-required_mark="required" id="email"
                                                               name="email" placeholder="Email Address"
                                                               type="text" value="">
                                                    </p>
                                                    <p class="et_pb_contact_field et_pb_contact_field_2 et_pb_contact_field_half et_pb_contact_field_last"
                                                       data-id="subject" data-type="input">


                                                        <label class="et_pb_contact_form_label" for="subject">Subject</label>
                                                        <input class="input" data-field_type="input" data-required_mark="required" id="subject"
                                                               name="subject" placeholder="Subject"
                                                               type="text" value="">
                                                    </p>
                                                    <p class="et_pb_contact_field et_pb_contact_field_3 et_pb_contact_field_last"
                                                       data-id="message" data-type="text">


                                                        <label class="et_pb_contact_form_label"
                                                               for="et_pb_contact_message_0">Message</label>
                                                        <textarea class="et_pb_contact_message input" data-field_type="text"
                                                                  data-required_mark="required"
                                                                  id="message"
                                                                  name="message"
                                                                  placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                                                    </p>
                                                    <input name="et_pb_contactform_submit_0" type="hidden"
                                                           value="et_contact_proccess">
                                                    <div class="et_contact_bottom_container">

                                                        <button class="et_pb_contact_submit et_pb_button" name="submit"
                                                                type="submit">Submit
                                                        </button>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <input id="_wpnonce-et-pb-contact-form-submitted-0"
                                                           name="_wpnonce-et-pb-contact-form-submitted-0"
                                                           type="hidden"
                                                           value="7dbdd1dfcb"><input name="_wp_http_referer"
                                                                                     type="hidden"
                                                                                     value="/?page_id=1750">
                                                                                                                                       
                                                
                                                </form>
```

That is what it looks like. I really need assistance. Anyone here that could help, would appreciate your time and efforts. thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do you want to display the message? On the next page? From what I understand when the form is submitted, the user browser goes to contact.php. Do you want to show the message there?

Comment: @zjbarg The browser, does not go to the next page. instead, the contact.php only performs required action to validate the form. since am not using JQeury.

Comment: However, have been able to work it out. But I changed the total appearance of the form.

Comment: Can you share you JS?